# Caliburn.Micro not updating UI

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, caliburn.micro

I'm trying to build simple utility with caliburn micro and wpf. This simple code:

```
    public bool CanTransfer
    {
        get { return this.canTransfer; }
        set
        {
            this.NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => this.CanTransfer);
            this.canTransfer = value;
        }
    }

    public void Transfer()
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(this.Process);
    }

    private void Process()
    {
        this.CanTransfer = false;
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        this.CanTransfer = true;
    }
```

Does the following - `Transfer` button remains disabled, but I'd expect it to be enabled 5 seconds after, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: It kind of feels a bit wasteful to take a thread from the pool just to make it sleep for 5 seconds. Can't you instead use a timer?

Comment: in my app a lot of things actually happen, but here is a simplified example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swap those lines in `CanTransfer` setter method - now you first say something has changed while it actually hasn't and then you change it:

```
public bool CanTransfer
{
    get { return this.canTransfer; }
    set
    {
        this.canTransfer = value;
        this.NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => this.CanTransfer);
    }
}
```

I usually use method like `ChangeAndNotify<T>` (the only annoyance is declaration of the field), the code can be seen [here](http://wpftutorial.net/INotifyPropertyChanged.html):

```
private bool _canTransfer;
public string CanTransfer
{
  get { return _canTransfer; }
  set 
  { 
    PropertyChanged.ChangeAndNotify(ref _canTransfer, value, () => CanTransfer); 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a notifiation:

```
this.NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => this.CanTransfer);
```

I hope I got the syntax right, I am typing from memory.
This basically tells WPF "Hey something changed, go and look at the new value".

Comment: Sorry, updated question text. Notification is in setter of a property